# I ordered, downloaded and installed Delphi XE Prof today - do I have the latest version automatically?

Tags: delphi

Today being: 24th of June, 2011

The about says : Embarcadero® Delphi® XE Version 15.0.3953.35171

Without having looked at every possible option, I don't immediately see a check for upgrade option.

Comment: use the check for updates item in the start menu

Comment: how is this question related to programming?

Comment: @David Hefferman: I thought there was an option in the menu structure. As I said, just installed it, and haven't taken the time to look for it thoroughly. @evilone: Not having all patches installed can lead to very long searches for 'bugs' which have been solved. So, yes, I find this a question about programming.

Comment: Please read the FAQ, @Evilone.

Comment: @evilone: Because it concerns an IDE, and that's on topic. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), as Rob said. (The question still isn't a good one, but it's on topic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David suggested, you can use Check for Updates in the Start menu.

This may or may not include all of the hot fixes.  You can find these on the [registered user downloads site](http://cc.embarcadero.com/myreg).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do.  Update 1 is the latest version for the IDE.  Update 2 is the latest for the Help Content.